# HEVC Deblocking with parallel processing on OpenCL

Tags: opencl, hevc

I have been working on HEVC for the past 2 years and recently I was asked to port the code of x265 onto OpenCL for parallel processing. Now, I am still at the starting stage and do see some concerns since Class is not a possibility as x265 uses many classes. Would it be possible to pass the structure since I have some function prototypes within the class. Is it possible to replicate the same onto GPU.

Comment: Is sycl option for you? https://www.khronos.org/sycl

Comment: @Jovasa, I already know about this option and I still need to think about using sycl for my solution. Thank you for the advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, as you have mentioned that we will not be able to pass a class to the Kernel function. However, you would be able to include the prototypes in the structure and pass it to the GPU.  You can refer to this link.  [passing parameters of an kernel function as C++ struct?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14673806/passing-parameters-of-an-kernel-function-as-c-struct)

Comment: Thank you for your advice. This is the answer I was looking for actually, I looked at the link and understand the procedure and I am sure I would be able to replicate the same.

Comment: @Matheen, I am glad you would be able to use this information.